# How do I restore MySQL .frm .MYD .MYI files in OS X Lion

Tags: mysql, database, database-restore, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restore mysql database from the physical files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250559/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-the-physical-files)

I received a bunch of these types of files and haven't a clue as how to restore the database on my Mac. I've found instructions on how to do this on Windows, that you simply need to put these into a specific directory and the database should be restored, but I don't know which directory, or even where it would be located in OS X.

Someone mentioned that I take a look at the my.cnf file, but it's empty. I also noticed that I had 2 mysql folders in usr/local/. I've uploaded a screen shot of the directory, as well as the opened cnf file at [Screen Shot 1](http://www.oliverkiss.com/images/temp/mysql_1.png)

Also, I opened up Sequel Pro (a MySQL client in case you're not familiar with the application) and it successfully connects to the local MySQL database. Screen shot at [Screen Shot 2](http://oliverkiss.com/images/temp/mysql_2.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default database directory should be `/usr/local/mysql/var` or `/usr/local/mysql/data` according to [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/osdb.html) (where /usr/local/mysql is just a symlink to the installed version). It would contain the "mysql" and "test" subdirectories for these two databases and the "ibdata1" storage file for InnoDB tables. You should just

- stop mysql
- create another subdirectory and name it like the database you need to restore
- copy your FRM, MYD and MYI files there
- restart mysql

to see the results. Note that this would only restore MyISAM tables, InnoDB tables may have had a different storage directory or have been stored within ibdata1 of the original server.