# Saving MySQL databases without mysqldump

Tags: linux, centos, migration, mysql

I need to back up some of my databases and migrate them over to a new server.

I would use mysqldump , but the problem is that I'm having issues starting mysqld/mysql (part of the reason I'm migrating). I kept getting

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Basically, I was on a media temple dv server and I used yum to try and upgrade stuff and that messed up a bunch of configuration because mediatemple didn't use yum originally to install mysql, php, etc...

ANYWAY, thankfully it appears my old tables are still around (I can see them in `/var/lib/mysql`)

**my question is**:
Is it possible for me to somehow migrate the files that are in my `/var/lib/mysql` to my new server? I was thinking I could possibly just "copy and paste" them into my new server's `/var/lib/mysql` directory... Would that theoretically work?

Or do I have any other options to move the tables?

I'm on CentOS.

Comment: There is already a good [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/250559/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-the-physical-files) regarding this problem. It should help you.

Comment: @JensBradler i followed those instructions .. i get the table showing up but it says it has no data in it :-\.

Comment: There is difference between MyISAM and INNODB tables. Which kind of table have you used?

Answer (score 2):

If every table you have uses the MyISAM storage engine, then copying /var/lib/mysql is just fine.

If even one tabe is InnoDB, then you must make sure you copy the following:

- /var/lib/mysql
- ibdata, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 (if they are not in /var/lib/mysql)
- /etc/my.cnf (because of the InnoDB settings)

Please make sure that when you restore /var/lib/mysql on another machine, it is safest to have the same major release of MySQL on that new server.

If you are upgrading from 5.1 to 5.5, copying /var/lib/mysql is out of the question for the grant tables because /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.frm has a different column layout amount versions.

- MySQL 5.0 has 37 columns
- MySQL 5.1 has 39 columns
- MySQL 5.5 has 42 columns

Answer (score 1):

Copying the content of /var/lib/mysql is not a beautiful solution, but it works if both MySQL versions are binary compatible to each other.

Which means in reality that MySQL 3 files wouldn't work with a MySQL 5.5 server. But usually when the source is a MySQL 5.x and the destination is also 5.x it should work.

I don't know if it could be an issue when the source is 32 Bit and the destination 64 Bit, though.